# Debian package, installation of dependencies

Tags: dependencies, package, debian

I'm building a Debian package which require others packages, such as libboost-all-dev or libqt4-dev by example. I've tried to use Pre-Depends and to put  apt-get install PKGS in preinst, but it doesn't work.

How can I launch automatically the installation of the dependencies ?

EDIT : My control file:

```
Package: myPackage
Version: 1.0
Section: base
Priority: optional
Depends: libboost-all-dev,libqt4-dev,libvtk6-dev,libcppunit-dev,libhdf5-dev,libann-dev,wx-common,libwxbase2.8-dev
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Corentin D <***@***.***>
Description: ...
Homepage: none
```

I'm trying to install the package using

```
dpkg -i package-name.deb
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the preinst script for that! Beside from the fact that it does not work because just a single instance of dpkg can run at a time the installation of the dependencies is a job for `apt`. Use the `control` file to list your binary dependencies as described in the Debian policy: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps

Further note that if you install a local package using `dpkg -i package-name.deb`, `dpkg` will not(!) install the dependencies listed in the control file. You still need to install them manually. If you want dependencies installed properly, you need to:

- Setup an Debian package repository (or use a ppa on Ubuntu)
- Place the `.deb` there
- Add the repository to your `sources.list`
- `apt-get update` or `aptitude update`
- `apt-get install package-name` or `aptitude install package-name`

Comment: I've tried to use Pre-Depends ans Depends, but still the same probleme. "MyPckg" depends of libboost-all-dev, libboost-all-dev is not installed..."

This is an extract from my control file :
...
Section: base
Depends: libboost-all-dev,libqt4-dev
Architecture: all
...

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Can you add the contents of the control file to the question?

Comment: Done. It's the same thing if I use Pre-depends or Depends.

Comment: The control file looks ok, but you are doing something wrong. I can't say what having just the information from the question. Did you uninstall the existing package before? Btw, a binary package should not depend on the dev versions of other packages.

Comment: how do you install the package? using `dpkg -i` or `apt-get install`?

Comment: I install the package using dpkg -i

Comment: `dpkg -i` will not install depencies. Only `apt` or `aptitude` doing so. With `dpkg -i` you need to install the dependencies manually

Comment: With apt-get install ./mypackage.deb, I get that :
Version "mypackage.deb" of "libio-socket-ip" is not found

(and lot of similar errors)

Comment: You cannot install local deb files using apt. `apt` works with repositories. ( sources.list). You need to setup a debian package repository and add it to your sources.list or create a ppa (private package repository) at launchpad site. However the latter is Ubuntu specific

Comment: You are welcome, Took me a while to find out the "real" problem :) `Depends` in your control file is ok then.